# Ruby - Deleting an element from a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
my_info = {'first_name' => 'xyz', 'last_name' => 'mnl', 'age' => 27}
```

When I try to delete the `age` key as follows:

```
my_info.delete['age']
```

I get the following:

```
r.rb:5:in `delete': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
        from r.rb:5
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason for that is because `delete` is a method so you must use parenthesis instead like this:

```
my_info.delete('age')
```